# Inheritance and constructors in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, superclass

How can I call the superclass constructor in the subclass constructor ? The following code doesn't work, what is missing ? I am confused. Thank you in advance for your help :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class Carre{
public:
    Carre(){}
    Carre(string nom){_nom=nom;}
    string getNom(){return _nom;}

protected:

    string _nom;

};

class Propriete : public Carre
{
public:
    Propriete(){}

    Propriete(string nom,const int prix):Carre(nom),_prix(prix){}
    int get_prix(){return _prix;}

protected:
    int _prix;

};

class Terrain : public Propriete
{
public:
    Terrain(){};
    Terrain(string nom,const int prix, const int loyer){
        Propriete(nom,prix);
        _loyer = loyer;}
    protected :
    int _loyer;

};


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    Terrain * T1 = new Terrain("T1", 6000, 120);
    cout << T1->getNom()<<" and "<<T1->get_prix() <<endl;

    delete T1;

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: Hint: you already know the answer because you did it in `Propriete`!

Comment: Please be more specific than ”doesn't work”.

Comment: A note on accepted nomenclature - in C++ we speak of "base" and "derived" classes, nor "superclass" and "subclass".

Comment: Ah, but for the days when mankind strove for a classless society...

Answer (score 0):

```
class Base
{
    protected:
        string s;

    public:
        Base(string s)
        : s(s) // Initialize member variable s from parameter s
        {
            // Do stuff
        }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    protected:
        int i;

    public:
        Derived(string s, int i)
        : Base(s), // Call base class constructor
          i(i)     // Initialize member variable i from parameter i
        {
            // Do stuff
        }

};
```

Comment: No need to explicitly call the base constructor in this case.